# Making a JQuery calculator, changing innerHTML but nothing is happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, innerhtml

I am making a jquery calculator, where by clicking on buttons that represent the numbers and operators on a calculator, the display's innerHTML would change to reflect the buttons clicked.

Below is my code:

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <title> JQuery Calculator </title>
  </head>
<body>

<style>

    section {
        padding: 2em;
    }

    .display {
        height: 5em;
        color: #333;
    }


</style>

    <section id="calculator">
        <div class="display">

        </div>

        <div id="numbersContainer">
            <table id="numbers">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="number" id="one">1</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>    
                        <button class="number" id="two">2</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="number" id="three">3</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="number" id="four">4</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>    
                        <button class="number" id="five">5</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="number" id="six">6</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="number" id="seven">7</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>    
                        <button class="number" id="eight">8</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="number" id="nine">9</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="number" id="zero">0</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table id="operators">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="operator" id="plus">+</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>    
                        <button class="operator" id="minus">-</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="operator" id="divide">/</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="operator" id="times">x</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>


    </section>

    <script>


        var storedCalculation;

        $('.number, .operator').click( function() {
            var numberOrOperator = event.target.innerHTML;
            storedCalculation+=numberOrOperator;
        });

        var calcScreen = $('.display').innerHTML;
        calcScreen = storedCalculation;


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the jsfiddle of it:
http://jsfiddle.net/ynf2qvqw/

Why is the innerHTML of the display class not changing?

Comment: FYI, your button elements don't contain HTML, so you should not use `innerHTML`. They only have text, so it would be safer to use the text content, probably via `$(event.target).text()`.

Comment: try http://codepen.io/mariusbalaj/pen/bGqhI

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/ynf2qvqw/2/

```
        var storedCalculation = '';

        $('.number, .operator').click(function () {
             var numberOrOperator = $(this).html();
            storedCalculation += numberOrOperator;
            $('.display').html(storedCalculation);
         });
```

You are using innerHTML incorrectly and you are trying to set your value outside of your click function.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery objects do not have an `innerHTML` property like native JavaScript HTMLElements. In order to modify a jQuery object's inner HTML, you must use the `html()` method, like so:

```
$('.display').html(storedCalculation);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/html/ for more information.

Answer (score 2):

**innerHTML** is not a property of jQuery. You can either set the innerHTML by grabbing the DOMElement from your selector:

```
$('.display').get(0).innerHTML = storedCalculation;
```

or you can use the jQuery **.html()** method:

```
$('.display').html(storedCalculation)
```

Comment: `$('.display').get(0)` is more formal than `$('.display')[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set the storedCalculation variable to an initial value for it to work better in general, otherwise the initial value will be "undefined".

```
var storedCalculation = "";
```

The next bit stays unaltered:

```
        $('.number, .operator').click( function() {
            var numberOrOperator = event.target.innerHTML;
            storedCalculation+=numberOrOperator;
```

Here, you use jQuery html() method. The paramter is the value you want to set, in your case storedCalculation.

```
            var calcScreen = $('#display1').html(storedCalculation);
        });
```

Hope I could help!